# I am not understanding how to use a solver on this example

Tags: excel, macos, solver

I understand i could you solver the problem i'm having is what to do with the Max number of plants and how to use it as a capacity.

[image: data for the products in the garden]
[image: Instructions for the data]

i added a solver because i couldn't use a capacity constraints on a goal seek and i have more than 1 decision to make to maximize my profit

Comment: Make the changing cells the numbers of plants, then those numbers have to be <= capacity.

Comment: This is in many books often called Product Mix. Check out Practical Management Science by Albright and Winston.

Answer (score 1):

So, just set this up as follows:

[image]

I will let you think about the calculations needed, but I have shown you what is set in the solver as well.